# Excel corrupted generated with Apache POI returned fronm API REST spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, apache-poi

EDIT :

If I hit directly the endpoint from the browser, the file is dowloaded correctly.
So I guess the problem is in the front and the way to create and save the file with the data received.

---

I have a java/spring boot application where I want to build an API endpoint that creates and returns a downloadable excel file. Here is my controller endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/informe/{informeDTO}")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> generarInforme(@PathVariable(value = "informeDTO") String informeDTOString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    
        

 final InformeDTO informeDTO =
                new ObjectMapper().readValue(informeDTOString, InformeDTO.class);
     
    List<InformeDTO> listDatosinformeDTO = utilsService.getDatosInformeDTO(informeDTO);

    for (InformeDTO informeDTO2 : listDatosinformeDTO) {
        logger.debug(informeDTO2);
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream in = createReport(listDatosinformeDTO);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=IOPreport.xlsx");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(in));

}
```

This is the angular controller :

```
  function generarInformeIOP(){
            
  
            InformesService.generarInformeIOP($scope.informeView.sociedad,  $scope.informeView.area, $scope.informeView.epigrafe,
                     $scope.informeView.cuenta, $scope.informeView.status, $scope.informeView.organizationalUnit, 
                     $scope.informeView.societyGL, $scope.informeView.calculationType, $scope.informeView.provincia, $scope.informeView.financialSegment,
                     $scope.informeView.loadDateFrom, $scope.informeView.loadDateTo,  $scope.informeView.incomeDateFrom,  $scope.informeView.incomeDateTo)
             .then(
                 function(response)
                 {
                     var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
                         type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
                     });
                     saveAs(blob, "IOPreport.xlsx");
                     
                      $scope.informeFunctionality.errorMessage = '';
                 },
                 function(errResponse)
                 {
                     console.log("ERROR: " + errResponse.data);
                     $scope.informeFunctionality.errorMessage = "Ha ocurrido un error inesperado: " + errResponse.data.error + 
                         ": " + errResponse.data.message;
                 }
             )
            
        }
```

And the service :

```
....
    $http.get(urls.SERVICE_API + "informe/"+ angular.toJson(informeDTO)).then(
                                function(response) {
                                    console.log("GenerarInformeIOP - success");
                                    deferred.resolve(response);
                                }, function(errResponse) {

                                    console.log("GenerarInformeIOP - error");
                                    deferred.reject(errResponse);

                                });
...
```

The generation is successfull, the file is downloaded but I think it is corrupted because Excel can't open it.

Are there anything wrong?

EDIT (adding createReport) :

```
        private ByteArrayInputStream createReport(List<InformeDTO> datosInforme) {
        ByteArrayInputStream result =null;
        
        try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            Set<String> columns = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

            // Coumnas fijas
            columns.add("Cuenta");
            columns.add("Epigrafe");
            columns.add("Descripcion");
            columns.add("Total_Importe");

            // Columnas dinamicas
            /*
             * Tedremos que recorrer todas las filas puesto que no sabremos si una traera
             * menos periodos que otra de esta manera obtendremos todos los periodos
             */
            for (InformeDTO informeDTO : datosInforme) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : informeDTO.getTotalByPeriodoContable().entrySet()) {
                    columns.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }

            /*
             * CreationHelper helps us create instances for various things like DataFormat,
             * Hyperlink, RichTextString etc in a format (HSSF, XSSF) independent way
             */
//          CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

            // Create a Sheet
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("IOPReport");

            // Create a Font for styling header cells
            Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
            headerFont.setBold(true);
            headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
            headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

            // Create a CellStyle with the font
            CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

            // Create a Row
            Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

            // Creating cells
            int i = 0;
            for (String value : columns) {
                Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellValue(value);
                cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
                i++;
            }

            // Create Other rows and cells with employees data
            int rowNum = 1;
            int cellDynamicNum = 0;
            for (InformeDTO informeDTO : datosInforme) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(informeDTO.getCuenta());
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(informeDTO.getEpigrafe());
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(informeDTO.getDescripcion_epigrafe());
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue("No Data");
                cellDynamicNum = 4;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : informeDTO.getTotalByPeriodoContable().entrySet()) {
                    row.createCell(cellDynamicNum).setCellValue(entry.getValue());
                    cellDynamicNum++;
                }

            }

            // Resize all columns to fit the content size
            for (i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
            }

            // Write the output to a file

            workbook.write(out);
             result = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            out.close();
            workbook.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Excepcion en la creacion del report " + e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Can you show the code for createReport(...) ?

Comment: Added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it adding the reponse type in the front call:

```
    var config = { responseType: 'blob' };
                        $http.get(urls.SERVICE_API + "informe/"+ angular.toJson(informeDTO), config).then(
....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When building the output here:

```
result = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

The workbook is not saved into `out` until it is closed. So you need to change the order to:

```
 workbook.close()
 result = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream is not necessary but it's fine if you leave it.

Comment: I did , but still the same problem, the excel file is downloaded fine but when I try to open it, I can't, it say there is a problem a can't open it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>` is used. I've another working solution which use byte-array `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`. Some of the code snippet are attached below:

After creating the workbook, write it to outputstream:

```
private final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

...
...
// at the end
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(stream);
return getDownload(stream.toByteArray(), filename, mediaType);

....
```

Download method:

```
    public static ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDownload(byte[] content, String filename, MediaType mediaType) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentLength(content.length);
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
        headers.setContentType(mediaType);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It didn't :  "Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Comment: @AntonioDiaz: if you got a solution to your problem. Can you please share your solution?